# Can't add image to mysql database

Tags: java

I want to add an image to the database.But nothing happens.There is a connection to the database.

```
     AssetManager assManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
      AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor = assManager.openFd("k.jpeg");
      FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = assetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();



      String newPath = path.toString();

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

      ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, byteArrayOutputStream);
      byte[] bytesImage = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

      String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(bytesImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
      PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO photo(id) VALUES (?)");
      FileInputStream  fin = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor);
                preparedStatement.setBinaryStream(1, fin);

      //Executing the statement
      preparedStatement.executeUpdate()
```

writes an error
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x01\xB4\xBF\x0D\x00...' for column 'id' at row

Comment: Prefer ```preparedStatement.executeUpdate();```  and then close ```preparedStatement```

Comment: so I also tried it, it doesn’t work anyway, the image is not added

Comment: Did you close the connection? Is auto commit true?

Comment: yes my problem is com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect string value: '\xE8\x1A\x11\xBE\x0D\x00...' for column 'id' at row 1

Comment: Hang on a minute, your query shows that you're attempting to set the *ID* column value. That is *not* the imsge itself

Comment: I understand that you need to translate in utf8mb4 format?

Comment: What is the *name* of the column?

Comment: my column is called id

Comment: Why are are you trying to add an image into a column called ID?

Comment: Just seen your last comment. So, you need to add an ID *and* the image

Comment: Yes, I need to add an image to the database with an ID

Comment: So do that. At the moment all you're doing is trying to add an ID but using the image as the value

Comment: How to add a simple image to the id column,?

Comment: Do you actually understand what an ID *is*?

Comment: I explain to you, I have an id column in which there are already images, now I want to add images there

Comment: Why is it called that and what is the column type? What's more what is the *actual* ID column called ( which all databases should have)?

Answer (score 2):

maybe you forget to set connection.

if your connection that's real have not been made.

You can connect to a database using the `getConnection()` method of the DriverManager class.

Connect to the MySQL database by passing the MySQL URL which is `jdbc:mysql://localhost/sampleDB` (where sampleDB is the database name), username and password as parameters to the getConnection() method.

```js
String mysqlUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/sampleDB";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(mysqlUrl, "root", "password")
```

semoga code ini bisa membantu anda

Comment: I connected to the database but I can't add an image

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-insert-images-in-database-using-jdbc. you can follow this link dude